# Reverse Causation

Tags: causality

I'm wondering whether red dots in the example scatterplot shown in the attached graphic can be used as an argument against reverse causation.

If the main effect was $Y \to X$, then we would assume that for high values of $Y$, we also get high values of $X$. However, $X$ appears to be assigned independently from $Y$, while $Y$ is not assigned independently from $X$.

Is the argument valid? If yes - how strong is it and can it be quantified? Is there literature on this?[image]

Comment: Why would you say that X "appears" to be assigned independently from Y and not vice versa? To me both directions provide equal amounts of information.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting the direction of causality is an active area of research. The first thing you need to know is that this is *impossible* without causal assumptions.

Therefore, in order to proceed, you need to make assumptions not expressible in terms of the joint distribution of observables. For instance, some methods focus on the [linear non-gaussian case](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/JMLR06.pdf), others have focused on ["independence" conditions of the distributions](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/NECO_a_00599) and so on.

In terms of literature, you can check a recent review by [Spirtes and Zhang here.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s40535-016-0018-x)  You might find [Chapter 2 of Pearl's Causality useful](http://amzn.to/2wbhUIl). Also, Peters, Janzing and Scholkopf have a new book out, [Elements of Causal inference](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elements-causal-inference), the pdf is free and they do focus on causal direction problems.

Comment: I would add Hernán, M. A. and Robins, J. M. (2018). [Causal Inference](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/). Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL. which is freely available in pre-print PDF after the link.

Comment: @Alexis as far as I know, they do not cover causal discovery in the book.

Comment: The OP did not ask about "causal discovery" but about "reverse causation," which the cited text contributes to, as well as serving as a solid pedagogical reference for introducing and motivating formal causal reasoning.

Comment: @Alexis finding out if x causes y or y causes x is refered to as causal discovery.